# Paths with spaces and wildcards

Tags: cmd, dos

I have this command line for loop

```
for /d %f in ("C:\Documents and Settings\Moi\Desktop\New Folder\*") do rmdir %f
```

It appears to be correct but it breaks up the path anyways even with the double quotes. I've tried using the hex equivalent (0x22) and that did not help either. Is there another way to handle paths with spaces in them?

If I simply try

```
for /d %f in ("C:\Documents and Settings\Moi\Desktop\New Folder\New Folder") do rmdir %f
```

It keeps the whole string but as soon as I add the wildcard it breaks the path up. The overall goal is to delete all the folders in this folder without deleting the folder itself.

Note:These are just test folders while trying to solve this problem, the real folders could be named anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quote the rmdir argument.  Also double the % when used in a batch file.

```
for /d %f in ("C:\Documents and Settings\Moi\Desktop\New Folder\*") do rmdir "%f"
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually solve this problem by using the old DOS 8 character path

- "Documents and settings" is: "docume~1"
- "Program  files" is "progra~1"
- "new folder" is newfol~1

If you have multiple similar names in a folder then the ~1 at the end is a counter

```
new folder = newfol~1
new folder2 = newfol~2
new folderhuppla = newfol~3
```

Comment: True this does snag the new folders specifically but these are just test folders. The real folders could be named anything.

Comment: Ofcourse, but the syntax is the same for any folder. Just make a function that takes the folder name, removes all spaces, takes the 6 first letters and add ~1 after it. There should also be a check to see if many folders are named the same the six first letters, in that case ~2 ~3 etc etc.

Comment: Worked for me inside Eclipse